# What does the || : in this line of bash script from an rpm spec file do?

Tags: bash, rpm-spec

```
ln -s /var/log/$SERVICE_NAME $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX/logs || :
```

In the rpm spec file every line ends with `|| :`

**What is the significance of the `|| :` and why is it there?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It causes any error to be ignored so that the rpm operation isn't canceled.

`||` causes the next command to run if the previous command failed, and `:` always succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

It swallows the exit code.

`||` does the thing after it if the thing before it fails (i.e., has a non-zero exit code). `:` is the “do nothing” command. Put them together…

Answer (score 2):

```
`||` is OR operator. `:` means "do nothing".
```

Your statement says, "do the soft linking or do nothing"

Answer (score 2):

I know others have answered, but I prefer to put:

`command || /bin/true`

IMHO that makes it a lot more obvious to the next person who is reading the bash script/spec file.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply means OR. You can try small testing like this

```
ls nofile-here-like || echo 'Not here'
```

If file not there echo will printed. Try with existing file, it will not